# jasmine error when I inject a Factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I ran a jasmine test over angular js, and i get the next error:

> PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) test_servicioCalculadora should provide
>   a version FAILED
>           /home/ivan/workspace/mobile.trackphone/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13218:53
>           forEach@/home/ivan/workspace/mobile.trackphone/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9168:24
>           loadModules@/home/ivan/workspace/mobile.trackphone/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13178:12
>           createInjector@/home/ivan/workspace/mobile.trackphone/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13104:22
>           workFn@/home/ivan/workspace/mobile.trackphone/www/lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3074:60
>           loaded@http://localhost:9876/context.js:151:17

I tried to change the routes, inject other service, and it's not working too
I ran other case like

```
it("compara un valor con otro", function () {
    var pi = 3.1415926,
      e = 2.78;

    expect(e).toBeLessThan(pi);
    expect(pi).not.toBeLessThan(e);
  });
```

and this's working fine.

This is my test file

```
describe("test_servicioCalculadora", function () {

  var calcu;

  beforeEach(module('starter'));

  it('should provide a version', inject(function(version) {
    expect(version).toEqual('v1');

  }));
});
```

my index.js is

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'LocalStorageModule',      'btford.socket-io', 'angularMoment', 'ngCordova', 'ngAudio']);


app.value('version', 'v1');
```

my karma.config.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [

      '../www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js',
      '../www/lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js', 
      '../www/js/index.js',
      '../tests/**/*-test.js' 
    ],
    exclude: [
    ],
    preprocessors: {
    },
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_ERROR,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
};
```

Comment: You are injecting a module that has too many dependencies, maybe one of them is failing to inject. Create a very simple module with no other injections and use it in your test, if it works then one of the dependencies is the problem.

Comment: i tried but it's not working

Comment: PhantomJS is known for swallowing errors that happen in beforeEach. Change it to Chrome for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to inject a value. Should be a service or a factory. 
e.g.

```
beforeEach(module('some.service', function($provide){
            var log = {
                info: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            }
            $provide.value('$log', log);
});
beforeEach(inject(function(_serviceName_){
  serviceName = _serviceName_;
}));

it("Actual test", function(){
   serviceName.performAction();
});
```

See the example, first is the module where you can set some values. Then is the service or factory at the end the test. 
This mean that the value of **log** will be injected on ***serviceName*** when is used on the actual test. 
Hope this help to clarify.